# How to parse a URL and run a method with Spring MVC 'reflectively'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring MVC in the usual manner, with a bunch of `@RequestMapping` methods, Freemarker definitions, and the like. This is all tied together with a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class.

I'd like to provide a service where the user submits a list of valid URLs, and the webapp would work out which controller would be called, passes in the parameters, and returns a combined result for every URL — all in one request.

This would save the user from having to make hundreds of HTTP calls, but would still allow them to make one-off requests if need be. Ideally, I'd just inject an auto-configured Spring bean, so I don't have to repeat the URL resolving and adapting and handling that Spring does internally, and the controller's list of other controllers would never go out of sync with the *real* list of controllers.

I expected to write something like this (simplified to only deal with one URL, which is pointless but easier to understand):

```
@Autowired BeanThatSolvesAllMyProblems allMappings;

@PostMapping(path = "/encode", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String encode(@RequestBody String inputPath) {
    if (allMappings.hasMappingForPath(inputPath)) {
        return allMappings.getMapping(inputPath).execute();
    } else {
        return "URL didn't match, sorry";
    }
}
```

Instead, I've had to define Spring beans I don't know what they do and have been repeating some of what Spring is meant to do for me, which I'm worried won't work *quite* the same as it would if the user just made the call themselves:

```
// these two are @Beans, with just their default constructor called.
@Autowired RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlers;
@Autowired RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

@PostMapping(path = "/encode", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String encode(@RequestBody String inputText) {
    final HttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest(null, inputText);
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    this.handlers.getHandlerMethods().forEach((requestMappingInfo, handlerMethod) -> {
        if (requestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition().getMatchingCondition(mockRequest) != null) {
            try {
                final MockHttpServletResponse mockResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
                result.append("Result: ").append(adapter.handle(mockRequest, mockResponse, handlerMethod));
                result.append(", ").append(mockResponse.getContentAsString());
                result.append("\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    });

    return result.toString();
}
```

I thought I was doing quite well going down this path, but it's failing with `Missing URI template variable` errors, and not only do I have no idea how to put the request parameters in (another thing which Spring could be able to handle itself), but I'm not even sure that this is the right way to go about doing this. So how do I simulate a Spring MVC request "reflectively", from within the webapp itself?

Comment: What's the real benefit here? It's entirely usual for clients to make lots of requests, and it's not considered a problem. The requests still have to be transmitted, and batching them somehow won't provide a significant speedup.

Comment: The actual use case is to extract URLs from a document and return the same document with the processed results in it, so it's available offline (or if the server goes down)

Comment: Then re-invoke the calls.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by invoke? Find an HTTP client library and use it to send calls to localhost?

Comment: Do you expect all these requests to be GET requests? Do you expect that the URL requests' results are all text based (JSON/XML)?

Comment: @ShankarPS: Yes to both!

Comment: Are you sure you can't represent it as a list of actions and always use one url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON API`](https://github.com/json-api/json-api) spec. solves this problem by allowing sending multiple operations per request. There even exists a quite mature implementation that supports this feature which is called [`Elide`](http://elide.io/). But I guess this is might not fully meet your requirements.

Anyway, here's what you can do.

You have to take into consideration that `DispatcherServlet` holds `handlerMappings` list that is used to detect appropriate `request` handler and `handlerAdaptors`. The selection strategy for both lists is configurable (see `DispatcherServlet#initHandlerMappings` and `#initHandlerAdapters`).

You should work out a way you would prefer to retrieve this lists of `handlerMappings`/`initHandlerAdapters` and stay in sync with `DispatcherServlet`.

After that you can implement your own `HandlerMapping`/`HandlerAdaptor` (or present a `Controller` method as in your example) that would handle the `request` to `/encode` path.

Btw, `HandlerMapping` as javadoc says is

> Interface to be implemented by objects that define a mapping between 
>   requests and handler objects

or simply saying if we take `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` that would map our `HttpServletRequests` to `@Controller` methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. Having this mapping `HandlerAdapter` prepares incoming request to consuming controller method, f.ex. extracting request `params`, `body` and using them to call controller's method.

Having this, you can extract `URL`s from main `request`, create a list of stub `HttpRequests` holding the information needed for further processing and loop through them calling this:

```
HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    for (HandlerMapping hm : this.handlerMappings) {
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace(
                    "Testing handler map [" + hm + "] in DispatcherServlet with name '" + getServletName() + "'");
        }
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = hm.getHandler(request);
        if (handler != null) {
            return handler;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

having a `handlerMapping` you call

```
    HandlerAdapter getHandlerAdapter(Object handler) throws ServletException {
    for (HandlerAdapter ha : this.handlerAdapters) {
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Testing handler adapter [" + ha + "]");
        }
        if (ha.supports(handler)) {
            return ha;
        }
    }
```

and then you can finally call

```
ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());
```

which in turn would execute the controller's method with params.

But having all this, I would not recommend to following this approach, instead, think about usage of `JSON API` spec or any other.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Springs `RestTemplate` as client for this? You could call your controllers within the spring controller as if it would be an external resource:

```
@ResponseBody
public List<String> encode(@RequestBody List inputPaths) {
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<>(inputPaths.size());
    for (Object inputPathObj : inputPaths) {
        String inputPath = (String) inputPathObj;
        try {
            RequestEntity.BodyBuilder requestBodyBuilder = RequestEntity.method(HttpMethod.GET, new URI(inputPath)); // change to appropriate HttpMethod, maybe some mapping?
            // add headers and stuff....
            final RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = requestBodyBuilder.build(); // when you have a request body change Void to e.g. String
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
            try {
                responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
            } catch (final HttpClientErrorException ex) {
                // add your exception handling here, e.g.
                responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getResponseHeaders(), ex.getStatusCode());
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                response.add(responseEntity.getBody());
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // exception handling here
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Note that generic do not work for the @RequestBody inputPaths.

See alse http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html and https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ .

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that you should consider this feature outside of your project, instead of having it in the code. It is a question of design and you can choose the approach you want. Based on your comment that these are GET requests, you can achieve what you want with a request dispatcher to trigger your requests within your special Controller service method for each URL and capture the response with a HttpServletResponseWrapper instance.

In the following code sample, the "consolidate" method takes comma separated URLs like this ("http://localhost:8080/index/index1,index2", here "index1,index2" is the URL list), consolidates their text output into a single payload and returns it. For this example URL, the consolidated outputs of http://localhost:8080/index1 and http://localhost:8080/index2 will be returned. You might want to extend/modify this with added parameters, validation, etc for the URLs. I tested this code with Spring Boot 1.2.x.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/index/{urls}")
    @ResponseBody
    String consolidate(@PathVariable String[] urls, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        StringBuilder responseBody = new StringBuilder();
        //iterate for each URL provided 
        for (String url : urls) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/" + url);
            HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
                private CharArrayWriter output = new CharArrayWriter();

                @Override
                public PrintWriter getWriter() {
                    return new PrintWriter(output);
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return output.toString();
                }
            };

            try {
                dispatcher.include(request, wrapper);
                //append the response text
                responseBody.append(wrapper.toString());
            } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        //This holds the consolidated output
        return responseBody.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index1")
    String index1() {
        return "index1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index2")
    String index2() {
        return "index2";
    }

}
```